# How to follow links with PyQT4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to do a search on google and then load the first link.

I modified some sample code I found online:

```
class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()  

url = 'https://www.google.com'
r = Render(url)
el = r.mainFrame().findFirstElement('input[name=q]')
el.setAttribute('value', 'stackoverflow')
button = r.mainFrame().findFirstElement('input[name=btnK]')

# Now click on the Search button
button.evaluateJavaScript('this.click()')

# Print out what we see
print r.frame.toHtml().toAscii()
```

This is supposed to click the Search button on my term 'stackoverflow'. But when I load the printed html, I only see the searchbar contain my text as though the search button hadn't been clicked yet.

How can I click on the search button, find the first result, and then print out the html source for it?

Answer (score 0):

So, I want to get this straight in my head... you're loading the default google page, setting the search text box to your search term, and then trying to emulate a click on "search?"

Wouldn't it be far easier to just access google's search directly?  i.e.:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow
```

Is there some reason you need to do indirectly through the web page?

Answer (score 0):

After a little poking around with the code, I found out that `button.isNull()` returns `True`. It basically means that there is no element called `input[name=btnK]`. So you might want to search for the right element.

However, initiating an instance is QApplication inside a Qt class is questionable and is not recommended. It can cause unknown/untold crashes. Here is how you could modify your code.

```
class Render( QWebPage ):
    def __init__( self, url ):

        # Init
        super( QWebPage, Render ).__init__( self )

        # Initial Signal-Slot connection
        self.loadFinished.connect( self.urlLoadFinished )

        # If you want to know what's happening
        sys.stdout.write( "Loading %s... " % url )
        sys.stdout.flush()

        # Start the load procedure
        self.mainFrame().load( QUrl( url ) )

    def urlLoadFinished( self, result ):

        # Loading complete
        print( "[DONE]" )

        # You do not want a loop back here once the button is clicked
        self.loadFinished.disconnect( self.urlLoadFinished )

        # Get your input element
        el = self.mainFrame().findFirstElement( 'input[name=q]' )

        # Fill it with the quesry you want
        el.setAttribute( 'value', 'stackoverflow' )

        # Get you Button
        button = self.mainFrame().findFirstElement( 'input[name=btnK]' )

        if not button.isNull() :
            # Connect the loadFinished signal to the final evaluation slot
            self.loadFinished.connect( self.printEvaluatedOutput )

            # Now click on the Search button
            print button.evaluateJavaScript( 'this.click()' )

        else:
            print "Button not found"
            qApp.quit()

    def printEvaluatedOutput( self ) :

        # Print the contents of the
        print self.mainFrame().toHtml().toAscii()

        qApp.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    app = QApplication( sys.argv )

    renderer = Render( 'https://www.google.com' )

    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

**EDIT1:**
After some more poking around, I found out that Google's search button gets registered with the name `btnG` rather than `btnK` as we see while inspecting the button. Replacing `input[name=btnk]` by `input[name=btnG]` does what you want.